# Notation for "or" in inclusion-exclusion formula

Tags: probability, notation, inclusion-exclusion

Suppose that I have a set $A$ and I want to compute the probability that this set contains at least one of the elements $x_1,\dots, x_n$. In other words,

$p(x_1 \in A \text{ or } \dots \text{ or } x_n \in A)$

I want to apply the inclusion-exclusion formula to compute this probability:
$p(x_1 \in A \text{ or } \dots \text{ or } x_n \in A) $

$ = \sum_{k_1=1}^n p( \{x_{k_1}\} \subset A) -  \sum_{k_1=1}^n \sum_{k_2=k_1}^n p(\{x_{k_1},x_{k_2}\} \subset A) + ... \\ + (-1)^{n-1} \sum_{k_1=1}^n \dots \sum_{k_n=k_{n-1}}^n p(\{x_{k_1},\dots x_{k_n}\} \subset A)$

Is this formula correct? Is there a better notation to show this that is easier to follow for the reader?

Comment: You want your $k_2$ summation to extend over $k_1<k_2$, and so on.

Comment: See [inclusion exclusion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle) as it shows a few compact ways to write it. Then adjust the format to instead talk about probability rather than cardinality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of taste, and what you perceive your audience's comfort level with notation to be.

If I were writing it, I'd first define $A_i$ to be the event that $x_i\in A$, and then write something like $$P(\bigcup_i A_i) = \sum_i P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j} P(A_i\cap A_j) + \cdots $$ and maybe say that $\bigcup A_i$ is the event that $x_1\in A$ or $x_2\in A$, etc.  The reason I prefer this notation is because it does not involve all those $\subset$ or $\in$ signs that your formula does.

Comment: I don't understand your notation completely. If $A_i$ is an event, is it meaningful to compute the intersection $A_i \cap A_j$? Shouldn't $A_i$ be defined as a set?

Comment: An "event" _is_ a subset of the "probability space", that is, of the set of all possible outcomes.  At least, according to the currently dominant set of definitions & notations in the field, as explained by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space .

Comment: @Paris Events are often identified with the set of ways they're true, or a set $S$ with the event $x\in S$. If you're unhappy with that, fair enough; "intersect" events with the logical conjunction $\land$ meaning *and* (and by the way, *or* is $\lor$). The mnemonic is obvious: giant Us, inverted or otherwise, become small Vs.